# How to find mean of struct datatype in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

## I want to find the eccentricity of an image.

```
 img = imread('47.jpg');
    ecc=regionprops(img,'Eccentricity');
    ecc = 

    255x1 struct array with fields:
        Eccentricity

    ecc(255)

    ans = 

        Eccentricity: 0.2851

    ecc(1)

    ans = 

        Eccentricity: 0.4740
```

=========================
ecc is a variable of struct datatype. It will hold values of all the 255 objects. However, I want to find only one eccentricity and considering the mean of all these values.

**Is there a way to find mean of struct value?**

I tried for loop. calculating sum and dividing by total no. of objects. But MATLAB does not permit addition on struct data varible.

=======================================

```
    img = imread('47.jpg');
    ecc=regionprops(img,'Eccentricity');
    numObj = numel(ecc);
    sum=0;
    index=1;
    for k = 1: numObj
        temp=ecc(index);
        **sum=temp+sum;**
        index=k+1;
    end
    imgEcc = sum/numObj;
**??? Undefined function or method 'plus' for input arguments of type 'struct'.**
```

===========================================

Please provide your inputs.

Comment: Try replacing `temp=ecc(index);` with `temp=ecc.Eccentricity(index);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Scalar Data in Field

Within your loop, you must refer to the field name to access the data:

```
for k = 1: numObj
    temp=ecc.Eccentricity(index);
    sum=temp+sum;
    index=k+1;
end
imgEcc = sum/numObj;
```

A more efficient method is to pull all of the eccentricities from the struct array using the fact that `ecc.Eccentricity` is itself a comma-separated list of values:

```
Eccentricities = [ecc.Eccentricity];
```

This is just like `[ecc(1).Eccentricity, ecc(2).Eccentricity,...]` by how Matlab handles struct arrays.
Since the eccentricities are now in a double array, you can use `mean`:

```
EccentricityBar = mean(Eccentricities);
```

### Array Data in Field

If the data in the struct array is not scalar, the semantics of the value extraction depend on the shape of data in the field.
Regardless of whether the field data is a row vector (`1xN`), a column vector (`Nx1`), or a matrix (`MxN`), the matrix formed by wrapping the field reference in square braces is always made from comma-separated concatenation.
In other words, if we have a struct array `foo` with field `bar`, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
baz1 = [foo(1:3).bar];
baz2 = [foo(1).bar,foo(2).bar,foo(3).bar];
```

To access certain elements of the `baz` array requires knowing the shape of the data in `foo(k).bar`.
If the data was a row vector of length `N`, the original columns from the struct array can be extracted using subscripts and the the stride `N`:

```
col1 = baz(1:N:end);
col2 = baz(2:N:end);
...
col# = baz(#:N:end);
```

If the data was a column vector of length `N`, the original rows from the struct array are the rows of `baz`:

```
row1 = baz(1,:);
row2 = baz(2,:);
...
row# = baz(#,:);
```

And for matrix data, combinations of the above two methods are where to look.

For example, if you had a struct array `data` with the field `Centroid` that had the `x` and `y` centroid locations in a `1x2 array`, we could extract the values like

```
centroids = [data.Centroid];
xbar      = centroids(1:2:end);
ybar      = centroids(2:2:end);
```

whereas, if the centroid locations were a `2x1 array`, we would extract like

```
centroids = [data.Centroid];
xbar      = centroids(1,:);
ybar      = centroids(2,:);
```

Comment: Thanks, Haskin. Second method helped me. I have a similar query. I want to perform this operation with centroid determination as well. However, in centroid there will be 2 values unlike in eccentricity. x-coordinate and y-coordinate. Can I store all x co-ordinates in one variable like xc=[stat.Centroid(2)]? MATLAB threw an error saying ??? Field reference for multiple structure elements that is followed by more
reference blocks is an error. It would be of help if there is some method to come around this.

Comment: Please see the expanded answer for how to extract non-scalar values.

Comment: Haskin, the centroid I got for the image under expt was a 255X1 struct array. Extracted the xbar and ybar as

Comment: Haskin, the centroid I got for the image under expt was a 255X1 struct array. Finding mean of xbar and ybar are returning me the very first and the last value in the array. Please have a look at the snippet. Pasting it in another comment below.

Comment: Looks like x and y co-ordinates are stored contiguously in the struct array [255by1] thus making the index size 510. I guess alternate values corresponding to x-co-ordinates. Please correct me   if I am wrong.

Comment: @parie I'm not sure what you mean. The shape of stat(1).Centroid determines the concatenation mode, but I don't known which component of the data represents `x` or `y`.  That's for you to know or find out if you are using a built-in MATLAB function.